# How to remove peer to peer records from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table like this:

Table1

```
id      serial_id product_id
59867   152905  10005646
59871   152900  10005646
168832  147721  10005646
220695  147721  10005646
```

Table2

```
211399  152900
220248  147721
```

I want to keep these records:

```
serial_id
152905
147721
```

my query:

```
SELECT REC.*
FROM Table1 REC
         LEFT JOIN Table2 REM ON REC.serial_id = REM.serial_id
WHERE
   REM.serial_id IS NULL;
```

but my query returns this result:

```
id      serial_id product_id
59867   152905  10005646
```

but at the first table I have two records of `serial_id: 147721`
I want to check these serials peer to peer and result must be:

```
id      serial_id product_id
59867   152905  10005646
220695  147721  10005646
```

Comment: why this particular record *168832  147721  10005646* will not display in the final result?

Comment: This is my question.

Comment: @Nick I  want to `Table1 - Table2`. at the first able `serial_id = 152905` exist.

Comment: @Nick but `serial_id = 147721` is duplicated at first table. I want to keep one of them.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick Server version: 10.3.20-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you want, you need to also look at the row number of each serial id in both tables, and add that to the `JOIN`. That way you can match each individual row in `Table1` to one in `Table2` and avoid removing both rows which have `serial_id = 147721`. Since you are using MariaDB 10.3 you can use `CTE`s and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serial_id ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM Table1
),
T2 AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serial_id ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM Table2
)
SELECT T1.id, T1.serial_id, T1.product_id
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.serial_id = T1.serial_id AND T2.rn = T1.rn
WHERE T2.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id      serial_id   product_id
220695  147721      10005646
59867   152905      10005646
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2fd59253dece438bd68f86ff9c3e164c)

Answer (score 0):

Changing LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN will do the job.

SELECT REC.*, REM.*
FROM TAB1 REC
INNER JOIN TAB2 REM ON REC.serial_id = REM.serial_id;

When you use LEFT JOIN and then add the condition REM.serial_id IS NULL, it will remove the matching records i.e. records with serial_id 152900 and 147721, as for the records with serial_id 152905, there is no matching record found in table2 and so table2 columns for he query will have null serial_id. Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a2de7/7/0) link, in this first query is the one you are using but without where clause and second one is the one i suggested.

Comment: This does not give OP's desired result